# Open a specific View Controller in PageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I am currently developing an iOS app with 3 View Controllers that are accessible by swiping right and left.

I want to have "WeatherVC" as the View Controller that is shown when the app is launched and I am struggling to figure this one out. 
I also want the specific order between the tabs to be: Tab 1 = ClimaVC - Tab 2 = WeatherVC - Tab 3 = ClosetVC.

Here is my code so far, with my 3 View Controllers:

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, 
UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

lazy var orderedViewControllers : [UIViewController] = {
return [self.newVC(viewController : "ClimaVC"),
        self.newVC(viewController : "WeatherVC"),
    self.newVC(viewController : "ClosetVC")]
}()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.dataSource = self



    //If let to check if firstViewController is not nil to use it.
                if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first{
                    setViewControllers([firstViewController],
                                       direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

    self.delegate = self
}


func newVC(viewController : String) -> UIViewController {

    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewController)


}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    //Guard = some kind of if statement.
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1;

    guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
       // return orderedViewControllers.last
        //Return nil to avoid swiping forever.
        return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]

}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    //Guard = some kind of if statement.
    guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.index(of: viewController) else {
        return nil
    }

    let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1;

    guard orderedViewControllers.count != nextIndex else {
        //return orderedViewControllers.first
        //Return nil to avoid swiping forever.
        return nil
    }

    guard orderedViewControllers.count > nextIndex else {
        return nil
    }

    return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot figure this one out & I spend quite some time trying!

Thanks guys!

Comment: The edit button doesn't seem to work so I'm gonna put it here. The order I want between the tabs is ClimaVC - WeatherVC - ClosetVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
setViewControllers([orderedViewControllers[1]],
                                   direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! I feel like I tried this option as I knew that orderedViewControllers was an array but I must not have done it the right away. Big up once again!

Answer (score 0):

Why not try UICollectionView?
UIPageViewController have some issues, this case don't need UIPageViewController